# How to know what to import?

Tags: ios

I have always been confused in finding out what i need to import in order to use a feature.

For example, when i use MFMailComposeViewController I know from googling that i need to

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

and add: MessageUI.framework

From the reference documentation, how do I know that i need these things?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

I want to learn how to better use the reference docs without relying on googling sample codes to find out what i need to import in the future, so can someone explain how to figure this out from documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how at the top it says it's declared in MFMailComposeViewController.h? The question then is what framework that's in. Here's one way to find out.

Start in an actual iOS project in Xcode. Press Shift-Command-O (File > Open Quickly) and paste or type MFMailComposeViewController into it. Open the listing for MFMailComposeViewController.h.

Now read the jump bar at the top of the editor. It says: ... > Frameworks > MessageUI.framework > ...

This lets you deduce that you need the MessageUI framework and that you need to import (not what you said, but) `<MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`.

Comment: That said, I regard the lack of direct info on this matter in the class documentation page as a bug in the documentation, and I recommend that you file a bug with Apple!

Comment: Note that many, but not all, of the reference pages list the framework the class belongs to in that top section as well.  Typically if it's neither in Foundation nor UIKit, you will also have to add the library to the "Link Binary..." build phase.

Comment: The import he used would work fine. There is no reason to import the entire framework if you are only using a class or two.

Comment: Note that every documentation page has a “Did this documentation help you?” bar at the bottom.  You can click the “Not helpful…” link there and tell them what's missing.  This is definitely easier than filing a radar bug report.  I've seen at least one error be corrected after I reported it this way.

Comment: One thing you forgot to mention is that you can alt+click on a declaration, and get a quick summary of what it's use is, and also a link to it's header file.

Comment: Thanks a lot the patience to answer a simple question! I never notice the jump bar at top can be use for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it and it might be useful to you too..

[image: Screenshot from Organiser]

Have you notice the navigation bar on the top? if you click "MFMailComposeViewController class Reference" field then it will give you something like this..

[image]

then you can see the "Message UI Framework Reference" and this  page tells you exactly what you need to import.. this is not perfect but it helps most of time...